# iPhone iOS how to change color of some words within UITextView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview

I'd like to offer a user of my app the ability to **highlight or change color of selected words** within a UITextView. I know how to change the entire text color:

```
 textView.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

This is not what I'm looking for. I need to know how to **change color of arbitrary sequences of characters** within a UITextView. I have not seen such feature in the text views up to date, so I think it's not supported out of the box. **Are there any open source projects or examples on how to change color or highlight blocks of text within a UITextView?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create CATextLayer and assign NSAttributed string to it. Have a look at [here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2011/03/attributed-strings-in-ios.html). You can make use of [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText/)