# is it possible to give a color to the selected part of the text in textview in ios programmatically

Tags: ios, highlighting, selectedtext

I want to change the selected part of the text in textview or highlighted the selected  text in textView.is it possible through any delegate methods of textView.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is it possible in iOS

Comment: May be these two questions might help you

1.[Link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751893/iphone-ios-how-to-change-color-of-some-words-within-uitextview)

2.[Link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4835576/how-to-add-placeholder-text-in-uitextview-in-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `textViewDidChangeSelection:` delegate method to be notified when the selection changes. Then use the `UITextView selectedRange` property to get the selected range.

Use the `UITextView attributedText` property to get the text view's attributed text. Create `NSMutableAttributedText` from that. And then apply the desired color attribute to the proper range. Finally, apply the updated attributed text to the text view.

All of this requires iOS 6.0 or later.